log hibernate statistics with seconds instead of nanoseconds
I am using Spring Boot with Hibernate and have implemented a custom session event listener to log Hibernate statistics with seconds instead of nanoseconds.
Previously, I registered my CustomStatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener using the setAutoListener method, as suggested by icyerasor in this post. However, setAutoListener is no longer available in Hibernate 6.
How to register custom listener in Hibernate 6 to log all hibernate statistics in seconds?
